# Abstract language tree generation doesn't work with specific syntax

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to build a console calculator by building an abstract syntax tree out of the specific tokens, including numbers, arithmetic operators and parentheses. I have got a recursive approach here:

```
def abstract_sny_mod(self, node, node_obj):
    if len(node) == 1:
        node_obj.content = node[0]
        return
```

The first part here simply puts an end to the recursion if there is a single number left. The function continues as follows:

```
    tknCounter = -1
    for token in node:
        tknCounter += 1
        check = None
        if token == "LPR":
            if node[-1] == "RPR":

                node_obj.content = node[1:-1]
                self.abstract_sny_mod(node_obj.content, node_obj)
                return
```

The above part just breaks up any expression completely surrounded by parentheses (`LPR` means left paren. and `RPR` right paren. respectively). And the last part generates two new nodes as left child and right child of the current node by splitting them up at a `PLS` or `MIN` token, provided it isn't inside parentheses (I didn't add `DIV` and `MUL` yet):

```
        if token == "PLS" or token == "MIN":
            check = node[tknCounter]

            leftSide = node[:tknCounter]

            if leftSide.count("LPR") > leftSide.count("RPR"):
                continue

            newNodeL = AbstractsnyTreeNode(node[:tknCounter], None, None)
            newNodeR = AbstractsnyTreeNode(node[tknCounter+1:], None, None)

            node_obj.content = check

            node_obj.left = newNodeL
            node_obj.right = newNodeR

            self.abstract_sny_mod(newNodeL.content, newNodeL)
            self.abstract_sny_mod(newNodeR.content, newNodeR)
```

This code works totally fine for inputs such as

```
["LPR", "5", "PLS", "5", "RPR", "PLS" "7"]
```

where the output would be (yes, I have a separate `__repr__` method for in this instance the head node of the tree):

```
|PLS |PLS 7 |5 5  v  v | v  v  v  v |
```

with v meaning "void". However inputs where the parentheses are not the first "part" of the expression generate some pretty bad outputs:

```
["5", "PLS", "LPR", "7", "PLS", "5", "RPR"]
```

gets:

```
|PLS |[] ['LPR', '7', 'PLS', '5'] | v  v  v  v |
```

even though the correct output would be:

```
|PLS |PLS 5 |7 5  v  v | v  v  v  v |
```

For reference, here is the TreeNode class, and its `__repr__`:

```
class AbstractSynTreeNode:
def __init__(self, content, left, right):
    self.content = content
    if len(self.content) == 1:
        self.content = self.content[0]
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

def __repr__(self):
    retstr = ""
    nodels = [self]
    i = -1
    while True:
        i += 1
        retstr += "|"

        for c in nodels:
            if not c:
                retstr += ' v '
            else:
                retstr += str(c.content) + " "

        newNodels = []
        for d in nodels:
            if d:
                newNodels.append(d.left)
                newNodels.append(d.right)

        if nodels == newNodels:
            break
        nodels = newNodels.copy()

    return retstr
```